# How can you solve a "File not found error: No such file or directory" when deploying on gcloud?

Tags: github, gcloud, file-not-found

Hi I am new to programming and I hope someone can help with this.
A team mate of mine did some changes yesterday through github and now we get this error when we want to "gcloud app deploy on our gcloud": "ERROR: gcloud crashed (FileNotFoundError): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/name/project/venv/bin/python3.8'."
The app itself still works but it seems we can not deploy anymore as we get this error. Really appreciate you reading this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error (`No such file or directory: '/home/name/project/venv/bin/python3.8'`) suggests that, a virtualenv (`venv`) was running (perhaps while `gcloud` was installed) and it is no longer effective (unable to find `/home/name/project/venv/bin/python3.8` in the path).

To reactivate the virtualenv, you can:

```sh
source /home/name/project/venv/bin/activate
```

Which should put `python3.8` back in your path:

```sh
which python3.8
/home/name/project/venv/bin/python3.8
```

And should return `gcloud` to a working state for the current shell session.

When that session ends, you'll need to rerun the `source ...` command.

It's good practice to explicitly `deactivate` the virtualenv when you're done with it.

Often, when running, the command shell is prefixed with `(venv)` to indicate that you're in a virtualenv:

```sh
# Create a virtualenv in `xxxx`
python3.8 -m venv xxxx

# Activate `xxxx`
me@host:~ $ source xxxx/bin/activate

# Note my prompt is prefixed with `(xxxx)`
(xxxx) me@host:~ $ which python3.8
/home/me/xxx/bin/python3.8

# Within the virtualenv, `python3.8` is ln'd
(xxxx) me@host:~ $ ls -l $(which python3.8)
/home/me/xxx/bin/python3.8 -> /usr/bin/python3.8

# Deactivate `xxxx`
(xxx) me@host:~ $ deactivate

me@host:~ $ which python3.8
/usr/bin/python3.8

(xxxx) me@host:~ $ deactivate
```

> **NOTE** In the example above, rather than use the customer `venv` directory, I'm using `xxxx` to demonstrate the point.